# Importing #defines, constants and typedefs from a DLL using ctypes

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I have a DLL from a board I bought to do some stuff, and it defines some functions, constants and types. I have successfully imported it to Python using ctypes. However, from this import I do not have access to the defined constants. For instance, if I need to call a function:

```
myDLL = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("path/to/dll/parrot.dll")

spam = myDll.eggs(THIS_CONSTANT) #THIS_CONSTANT is defined in the DLL
```

then I cannot do it.
Is there a way to have access to these constants?

Comment: Yet an other reason to avoid `#define`s in your C libraries. Search for the documentation of the library and use the value documented there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#define` are certainly *not* accessible from the DLL. Indeed, their definition is expanded by the preprocessor even before the compiler starts to work. So there is no way the DLL remember the name under which it was defined.

Comment: That settles it for #defines. But still, if in a regular C/C++ program I would have access to constants, then there has to be a way to have access to them in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You need to translate the header file into equivalent Python ctypes code. That can be done manually, or perhaps using a tool to automate some or all of the conversion.